# How do I add 2 more pictures to this ffmpeg slideshow?

Tags: ffmpeg

This is the command I use to make the slideshow with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.wav -framerate 1/4 -t 60 -loop 1 -i first.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i Test.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i test-ceinture-running-flip-belt.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i Wikimedia_Outreach_test_logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v0]; [2:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v1]; [3:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v2]; [4:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v3]; [v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0 [out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:0 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 20 -keyint_min 100 -f mp4 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p out_024.mp4
```

I would like to add 2 more pictures that lasts 600 seconds each.

Could you please help me?

Comment: If you would have taken the time to put a few line breaks into the pasted command, you would have probably figured this out by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you experiment manipulating your current command? everything is there. According to your approach you can achieve this as follows.

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.wav -framerate 1/4 -t 60 -loop 1 -i first.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i Test.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i test-ceinture-running-flip-belt.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i Wikimedia_Outreach_test_logo.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i new_image_1.png -framerate 1/4 -t 600 -loop 1 -i new_image_2.png -filter_complex "
[1:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v0];
[2:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v1];
[3:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v2];
[4:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v3];
[5:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v4];
[6:v]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:0+(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:0+(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2 [v5];
[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5]concat=n=6:v=1:a=0 [out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:0 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 20 -keyint_min 100 -f mp4 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p out_024.mp4
```

But the way you have done this is not efficient. You may need to reed the [relevant documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) first. You can rename the image files with common settings like `-framerate 1/4 -t 600` to something like `img%03d.png`. It will help you to reduce the command length as well as the performance aspect at the execution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem which will help other people with the same problem.